# How to cat contents of multiple files from a python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, cat

I would like to `cat` the contents of the files generated from a python script.  Is it possible to do that in a simple one line command?  For example I would like to have something like:

```
cat <(python test.py) # doesnt work as I want to
```

where test.py produces multiple filenames like so (separated by new line)

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I would like to basically do

```
cat file1.txt
cat file2.txt
cat file3.txt
```

Basically reading the contents of the filename produced by the script. Assume the python script can generate hundreds/thousands of filenames.

Though this may seem to work

```
cat $(python test.py)
```

But the problem is it seems to wait until the whole `python test.py` is completed, before it performs any `cat`.  Basically it doesnt seem to cat the contents of the filename as soon as it gets a filename.  Where as

```
cat <(python test.py)
```

`cat` the filename as it gets it, unfortunately, it just prints the filename but not the content of the filename.

Comment: `cat <(python test.py)` doesn't work as you expect, since it doesn't know there's more input to come. It waits for input, receive the first line, executes and finishes. Why not adding the `cat <file>` login into the python script with a cli option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^/cat /e' <(python3 test.py)
```

This will add `cat` in front of each filename before executing the command.

`^` - This will anchor the find to the start of each line

`cat` - cat will replace the anchor at the start of each line

`e` - This tells sed to execute the commmand that resulted from the substitution, in this case `cat file1.txt`

Comment: This works well, thanks.  Can you explain a little bit more on how the sed parameters are for?  Substitute every beginning with cat?  Whats the /e for

Comment: @user1179317 Please check edit

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create the STDOUT with these files in your script:

For example **test.py**

```py
import os
for i in range(0,5):
  name="file" + str(i) +".txt"
  f = open(name, "a")
  f.write("Hello\n")
  f.close()
  print(name)
```

Something like this:

```sh
$ python test.py
file0.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt

$ cat $(python test.py)
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

If you want the *cat* to work on the fly, it's not so simple because in the **single line bash** we have to wait for the previous command to finish.
But you can try to do something like this:

```sh
$ python test.py > /dev/null &
$ watch -n10 'find ./  -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -10s -exec cat {} \;'
```

My example:

```sh
$ 
$ ls
test.py
$ cat test.py 
import os
import time
for i in range(0,500):
  name="file" + str(i) +".txt"
  f = open(name, "a")
  f.write("Hello" + str(i) +"\n")
  f.close()
  print(name)
  time.sleep(1)
$ python test.py >/dev/null &
[1] 28579
$ 
$ watch -n10 'find ./  -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -10s -exec cat {} \;'
```

```sh
Every 10.0s: find ./  -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -10s -exec cat {} \;                                                                                                                     MacBook-Air-Viktor.local: Sun Dec 12 10:41:49 2021

Hello264
Hello265
Hello267
Hello266
Hello262
Hello263
Hello261
Hello260
Hello268
```

Comment: If you add sleep on that script, the cat will not print anything until the entire script is done.  Even if you flush the stdout

Comment: In this case, it will work. Because we use a file system as a buffer. The first line works in the background, the second line reads new files. I can't add code to this comment and I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `sed`, as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70321559/4955498), you should consider `xargs`:

```
python3 test.py | xargs -i cat "{}"
```

This is more robust than `sed` + `cat` since, unlike the `sed` solution, it works well with filenames that contain many unconventional characters such as `'*'`, `'?'`, and `' '` (but not with `'\n'`).

A minor change to your python script, can make it work well with filenames also having `'\n'` characters. The change in the python scripts will use `'\0'` instead of `'\n'` to separate the filenames (make sure to flush stdout after each such filename). Then use `xargs` with the `-0` argument:

```
python3 test.py | xargs -0 -i cat "{}"
```

Now, once you use `\0` instead of `\n` to separate filenames, your solution works well for all possible filenames.